# Android, get screen width and height?

Tags: android

I am trying to get the width and height of the screen in Android, i have:

```
DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
stageWidth = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
stageHeight = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
```

The width is 1280 but its coming back with 752.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
stageWidth = display.getWidth();
stageHeight = display.getHeigth();
```

Is that the same width? Are you sure the width is 1280 and not 752? What device are you testing it on and what height are you getting?

Comment: those methods are deprecated. You should use: `getSize(Point outSize)`

Comment: @DanielS  What do you mean by Point outsize?  What does that parameter look like when calculating the height of the display?

Comment: The outSize object will contain the size of the display (adjusted for orientation). The doc is here - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html#getSize(android.graphics.Point)

Answer (score 0):

Use this method on the display object (from the docs):

`void    getSize(Point outSize) - 
Returns the raw size of the display, in pixels.`

Comment: It's a method in the Display object. Just create a new point object and pass it to the method. Once it returns it should have the proper information inside of it. Post your results here and let us know if it worked out.

Answer (score 0):

Rotate your screen and see.I think you will get your correct screen size.

The above code worked with me and should work with you.